# Blender performance issues with generating UV spheres

Tags: python, python-3.x, blender, blender-2.61

When I run this script:

```
import bpy, time
t0 = time.time()

for i in range(1000):
    bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_uv_sphere_add()

    if i % 100 == 0:
        print(time.time()-t0)
        t0 = time.time()
```

This is the output (exponential growth vs. time):

```
1.1920928955078125e-05
0.44658803939819336
0.46373510360717773
0.5661759376525879
0.7258329391479492
0.9994637966156006
1.381392002105713
1.8257861137390137
2.4634311199188232
3.2817111015319824
```

Why does this happen? Is there a better approach?

I am running this on a server with ample memory, and I know Blender can expand to use most of it (it does in rendering).

Comment: Did you try to move your spheres, or add them to a currently invisible layer? My wild guess is that a redraw may be somehow triggered by adding spheres, and redrawing 1000 spheres maybe slowing the process down.

Comment: That's definitely a good guess, but I don't think that's what's happening. The spheres only draw when the script completes, and I see the same behavior for selected and invisible layers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The quick answer:

```
bpy.ops.object.select_all(action='DESELECT')
bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_uv_sphere_add()
sphere = bpy.context.object

for i in range(1000):
    ob = sphere.copy()
    ob.data = sphere.data.copy()
    bpy.context.scene.objects.link(ob)
bpy.context.scene.update()
```

Explanation:

Anything in `bpy.ops.*` causes a scene redraw with each call. You want to avoid calling these in loops. The above script calls lower-level `copy()` methods, which don't redraw. If you want linked duplicates, you can remove the `sphere.data.copy()` line.

This solution is not my own. Kudos go to CoDEmanX over at [BlenderArtists](http://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?273149-Generating-a-large-number-of-mesh-primitives) for this answer!